# Sending email from webhosting without having to use username and password

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, email

I have written a C# program to send an email, which works perfectly.
Additionally, I have a PHP script to send emails, which works perfectly aswell.

But my question is :
Is it possible to send an email with C# like you do from PHP where you don't need to specify credentials, server, ports, etc.

I would like to use C# instead of PHP, because I am creating an ASP.Net web application.

This is my current C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
public partial class $safeitemname$ : Form
{
    public $safeitemname$()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AttachB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AttachDia.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string AttachF1 = AttachDia.FileName.ToString();
            AttachTB.Text = AttachF1;
            AttachPB.Visible = true;
            AttachIIB.Visible = true;
            AttachB.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void AttachIIB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AttachDia.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string AttachF1 = AttachDia.FileName.ToString();
            AttachIITB.Text = AttachF1;
            AttachPB.Visible = true;

        }
    }





    private void SendB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(EmailSmtpAdresTB.Text);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 20000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(EmailUserNameTB.Text, EmailUserPasswordTB.Text);
            MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
            Msg.To.Add(SendToTB.Text);
            Msg.From = new MailAddress(SendFromTB.Text);
            Msg.Subject = SubjectTB.Text;
            Msg.Body = EmailTB.Text;

            /// Add Attachments to mail or Not
            if (AttachTB.Text == "")
            {
                if (EmailSmtpPortTB.Text != null)
                    client.Port = System.Convert.ToInt32(EmailSmtpPortTB.Text);

                client.Send(Msg);
                MessageBox.Show("Successfuly Send Message !");
            }
            else 
            {
                Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(AttachTB.Text));
                Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(AttachIITB.Text));
                if (EmailSmtpPortTB.Text != null)
                client.Port = System.Convert.ToInt32(EmailSmtpPortTB.Text);

                client.Send(Msg);
                MessageBox.Show("Successfuly Send Message !");
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void settingsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.settingsBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.awDushiHomesDBDataSet);

    }

    private void awDushiHomesEmail_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'awDushiHomesDBDataSet.Settings' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.settingsTableAdapter.Fill(this.awDushiHomesDBDataSet.Settings);

    }
  }
}
```

This is how it is done in PHP:

```
<?php
//define the receiver of the email
$to = 'test@hotmail.com';

//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'Test email with attachment';

//create a boundary string. It must be unique
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));

//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";

//add boundary string and mime type specification
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";

//read the atachment file contents into a string,
//encode it with MIME base64,
//and split it into smaller chunks
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('PDFs\Doc1.pdf')));

//define the body of the message.
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
?>

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>"

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!!
This is simple text email message.

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p>

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: application/zip; name="Doc1.pdf" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

<?php echo $attachment; ?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--

<?php
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer
$message = ob_get_clean();

//send the email
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed"
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
?>
```

I'm not asking for you to write my code but maybe you could provide some info  or let me know if its possible or not.

Edit:

My question is not about not using a smtp server but how to send an email without having to enter username and password. I know, that it will only work if the request to send the email comes from my server.

Comment: Actually PHP *does* use [various mail server settings](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php), however they are stored in the php.ini file and have built-in default values. I would assume you could change them at run time with `ini_set()` if you did need to make changes that are not system-wide.

Comment: @Mike I didn't really know what to look for but i googled a lot, maybe for the wrong things... i will try the links you gave me. client.UseDefaultCredentials = true; looks promising.

Comment: Actually I removed my last comment because I don't think that does what I thought it did. It appears that's used when you need to authenticate with the mail server. Correct me if I'm wrong. I don't know C# at all.

Comment: You provided some code and stated a goal, but you didn't say how your code isn't behaving as you expect it to. Does it throw an error? What's the error?

Comment: @mason There is no error its working but i would like to make it like in php without having to specify an account , server or the rest. like the php code i posted "it works without entering email acount info , smtp server info" etc. how to do that in c# i cant figure out.

Comment: PHP isn't magic. You have to tell it where the mail server is too.

Comment: Check my answer on how and what can be done. And the PHP code you posted use smtp in the `@mail()` mehtod which you can see a sample of here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mail.asp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why in PHP you can send a mail without specifying SMTP credentials is that someone else already configured php.ini or sendmail.ini for you (files that the PHP interpreter uses to get some values).

This is usually the case with managed hosting (or if you use PHP on your development PC with tools like AMPPS, which can make you easily edit the SMTP settings through a UI and forget it).

In ASP.NET / C# there is the **app.config** or **web.config** file, where you can inject SMTP settings (in the [`<mailSettings>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w355a94k(v=vs.110).aspx) tag) and therefore achieve the same result as PHP (the `SmtpClient` will automatically use the credentials stored there).

Check these questions for an example:

[SmtpClient and app.config system.net configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244589/smtpclient-and-app-config-system-net-configuration)

[SMTP Authentication with config file's MailSettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621169/smtp-authentication-with-config-files-mailsettings)

Comment: And this is exactly an answer. PHP server has to be already configured by someone, to make `mail` work.

Comment: Additionally you could state that he could scratch the credentials if an SMTP which doesn't need authentication is configured.

Answer (score 1):

At these posts, to which likely this will be a duplicate of, you will find a couple of ways how to send email using ASP.NET.

- [How to send email in ASP.NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326738/how-to-send-email-in-asp-net-c-sharp)
- [Sending mail without installing an SMTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637866/sending-mail-without-installing-an-smtp-server)

**Note:** You can't send email without a smtp server, though you don't need one of your own if someone else let you use their's.

Comment: he like send email without using smtp

Comment: @GoudaElalfy Updated my answer, and a smtp server is needed somewhere ... even with php.

Comment: @LGSon i got it to work from the How to send email in ASP.NET C# link you gave me.the only funny thing is it takes 30 minutes to get the email. but i gues it had nothing to do with the code but with the server.

Comment: My question was not about not using a smtp server but how to make it without having to enter username and password.feels more save to me.what i know it will only work now if the request to send the email comes from my server.

Comment: @Creator Okay, and yes, it can sometime take time for mails to get through ... :) ... and I'm glad you found a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have php installed in your server you can simply send email through php main function. You don't need credentials.

The built-in email sending function of php is

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

You can use this code for detail understanding

```
// recipients
  $to  = "hello@hellosofts.com"; // note the comma
  // subject
  $subject = 'Testing Email';

  // message
    $message = " Hello, I am sending email";

  // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

  // Additional headers
  $headers .= 'To: 'Zahir' <'zahir@hellosofts.com'>' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'From: Admin | Hello Softs <do-not-reply@Hellosofts.com>' . "\r\n";


  // Mail it
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Host : localhost
OS : Ubuntu 12.04 +
Language : PHP
```

Install **sendmail** in your OS

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

Create a file **test-mail.php**
Write code inside :

```
<?php
$to      = 'test_to@abc.com';
$subject = 'Test Mail';
$message = 'hello how are you ?';
$headers = 'From: test_from@abc.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: test_from@abc.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo "Mail send";
}else{
    echo "Not send";
}

echo "Now here";
?>
```

Mail will be sent to **test_to@abc.com**

**Note** : You don;t need to write username/password.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the mail settings section within the web.config file in your web application as shown below. If your site is hosted by a third party hosting company, you can ask them for smtp details (smtp username, smtp password, server name or IP and the port number). If you have this configuration in web.config and smtp is enabled (on the server), then you should be able to send emails without specifying the credentials in c# code.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="you@yoursite.com">
        <network password="password01" userName="smtpUsername" host="smtp.server.com" port="25"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you send mail without SMTP or "without having" credentials : No ..

If you don't want to write your credentials in your php files(in the development stage) you can use `.env`

https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

example `.env` file:

```
DB_HOST='example'
DB_PORT='example'
DB_USER='postgres'
DB_PASS='example'
SMTP_HOST='example'
SMTP_PORT='example'
SMTP_USER='example'
SMTP_PASS='example'
HOST='example'
```

then you can use these env variables in your php files:

```
getenv('SMTP_USER')
```

Also you can crypt the .env file or set no public access .But these aren't the most important security concerns someone should care.. If someone breaks into your server,you are already in trouble..

I'm not a .NET MVC developer but you can [set environmental variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x(v=vs.110).aspx)(in the development stage) too

Anyway you need to write them somewhere or they are already written..And it's not a big security concern unless you post your code somewhere like github etc..

NOTE THAT:having environmental variables may cause performance problems in the production especially with php